# SAS: How to prevent "WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro not resolved" within a libname statement?

Tags: sas

I have to use a password similar to the password below within a LIBNAME statement. The password includes a percentage sign (%) which results in the WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro PS not resolved:

```
LIBNAME EXAMPLE ORACLE
user=user1
password="'thisisapassword%PS|("
PATH=PATH1
SCHEMA=SCHEMA1
;
```

Because the password already includes a single quote, I have to use double quotes for the password, eventually resulting in a warning due to the percentage sign being used

I can't find how to escape this % or any other way to prevent this warning from occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the password in single quotes to prevent interaction with the macro system.  Double up the single quote within the single quotes if the password literally contains a single quote.

Example:

```
PROC PWENCODE IN='''thisisapassword%PS|(';
/*                ^^                         ^^ showing where doubling up is needed */
```

From the documentation "[Using Quotation Marks with Character Constants](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n16x35flo6ajhqn10cqfr7hnanib)" *(**my bold**)*:

> If a character constant includes a single quotation mark, enclose it in double quotation marks. For example, to specify the character value `Tom's` as a constant, enter the following:
>
> `name="Tom's";`
>
> Another way to write the same string is to enclose the string in single quotation marks and to express the apostrophe as two consecutive quotation marks. **SAS treats the two consecutive quotation marks as one quotation mark**:
>
> `name='Tom''s';`
>
> The same principle holds true for double quotation marks and the character value `Tom"s`:
>
> `name="Tom""s";`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can test it. I can't test beacuse we don't use this characters in paswords but this can run witouth warning:

```
PROC PWENCODE IN="'thisisapassword%PS|(";
run;
%put &_PWENCODE;

LIBNAME EXAMPLE ORACLE
user=user1
password="&_PWENCODE"
PATH=PATH1
SCHEMA=SCHEMA1
;
```